# Need to compare total score from multiple constraint streams

Tags: optaplanner

In a two entity model, a score to minimize a resource is the sum of two Constraint Streams.  I need to constrain the sum of the values from the two constraint streams in order to cap a resource - and penalize when the count exceeds a certain level. With one constraint stream (score), this comparison is easily performed, but with the score coming from two streams, I'm kinda left to a trial-and-error approach of constraining the individual scores.

Is there a way to evaluate the total score in the constraint stream?  Or is there another way to achieve this?

The two constraints are listed below.  The relationship between SelectedScenario and SelectedRoute is many-to-many.  SelectedScenario and SelectedRoute are the two planning entities.  Each entity has an on/off planning variable.  It's an overlapping set covering problem.  There is no convexity.  Another constraint posts a difficulty score providing some convexity.

```java
// Route Count

//  Begin with the count of active runs, presuming that each is on a single route.  The
//  active runs on routes are deducted in the next objective (creditRouteRunReduction)
Constraint runsOnActiveScenarios(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(SelectedScenario.class)
            .filter(selectedScenario -> selectedScenario.getOnOff().isOnOff())
            .penalize(BendableScore.ofSoft(BENDABLE_SCORE_HARD_LEVELS_SIZE, BENDABLE_SCORE_SOFT_LEVELS_SIZE, 2, 1),
                    ((selectedScenario) -> selectedScenario.getRunCount()))
            .asConstraint("runsOnActiveScenarios");
}

// Reduce the route count by the number of runs on full routes minus one for the route
Constraint creditRouteRunReduction(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(SelectedRoute.class)
            .filter(selectedRoute -> selectedRoute.getRouteOnOff().isOnOff())
            .join(RouteScenario.class, Joiners.equal((selectedRoute) -> selectedRoute.getRoute(), RouteScenario::getRoute))
            .join(SelectedScenario.class, Joiners.equal((selectedRoute, routeScenario) -> routeScenario.getScenario(), SelectedScenario::getScenario))
            .filter((selectedRoute, routeScenario, selectedScenario) -> selectedScenario.getOnOff().isOnOff())
            .groupBy((selectedRoute, routeScenario, selectedScenario) -> selectedRoute, countTri())
            .filter((selectedRoute, count) -> selectedRoute.getRunCount() == count)
            .reward(BendableScore.ofSoft(BENDABLE_SCORE_HARD_LEVELS_SIZE, BENDABLE_SCORE_SOFT_LEVELS_SIZE, 2, 1),
                    (selectedRoute, count) -> selectedRoute.getRunCount() - 1)
            .asConstraint("creditRouteRunReduction");
}
```

Comment: You did not describe whether each stream is governed by a linear relationship, nor whether there is convexity in this problem. [Show](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) us the code, even if what you have is not yet working properly.

Comment: I added the two constraints to the post. The code works. 
The relationship between SelectedScenario and SelectedRoute is many-to-many.  SelectedScenario and SelectedRoute are the two planning entities.  Each entity has an on/off planning variable.  It's two entity overlapping set covering problem with no convexity.  Another constraint posts a difficulty score providing some convexity.